# How to test keyboard is pressed in textarea on webview ios?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I stuck few hours about this problem. I have webview that contain textarea so i want to know how to know when user press a key.

Comment: U need to work on JavaScript.In native UiWebView doesn't support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Javascript in this case. Please take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get JavaScript involved, check below questions:

[How to detect keyboard enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476127/how-to-detect-keyboard-enter-key)

[UIWebView, customize "return" key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970848/uiwebview-customize-return-key)