# UIWebview keyboard return key pressed ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ios7

i am trying to find out a solution when the return key of UIWebview is clicked !
i tried the  following links but it's not working !

[UIWebView, customize "return" key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970848/uiwebview-customize-return-key)

[How to detect keyboard enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476127/how-to-detect-keyboard-enter-key)

i want to do some offset work when user is typing on the UIWebview and return key is pressed !

Here is the code i am using !

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString* plainContent = @"Edit here.....";
    NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"<html>"
                                   "<body>"

                                   "<div id=\"content\" contenteditable=\"true\" style=\"font-family: Arial\">"
                                   "%@"
                                   "</div>"

                                   "</body></html>", plainContent];

    [_webview loadHTMLString:htmlContentString baseURL:nil];
}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString *theTask = (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:0];

    if([[[request URL] absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"enterClicked"].location!=NSNotFound)    // When "enterClicked" found
    {
        NSLog(@"enterClicked !");
        //Do your desired work
        return NO;
    }
    if([theTask isEqualToString:@"returnkeypressed"]){
        NSLog(@"theTask");
        [aWebView endEditing:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the answer of [UIWebView, customize "return" key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970848/uiwebview-customize-return-key) didn't work?

I try that and work for me, I only change the method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` to:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSString *theTask = (NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:0];

    if([theTask isEqualToString:@"returnkeypressed"]){
        [aWebView endEditing:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Another way is using a buffer text view, like my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961369/how-the-default-keyboard-comes-up-when-user-taps-in-uiwebview/20037193#20037193) for change the keyboard.

Edit: you need add the script to detect the return key:

```
NSString* plainContent = @"Edit here.....";

NSString* htmlContentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"<html>"
                                "<head>"
                                    "<script>"
                                        "function returnKeyPressed(event){"
                                            "if(window.event.keyCode == 13)"
                                                "document.location = \"returnkeypressed:\";"
                                            "return true;"
                                        "}"
                                    "</script>"
                                "</head>"
                                "<body onKeyPress=\"return returnKeyPressed(event)\">"
                                    "<div id=\"content\" contenteditable=\"true\" style=\"font-family: Arial\">%@"
                                    "</div>"
                                "</body>"
                               "</html>",
                               plainContent];
```

Comment: i am not sure about but may b because of ios 7.

Comment: So check my another suggestion. In the meanwhile I will check in iOS 7.

Comment: Well ! i don't want to add a new UITextview inside the webview as i am allowing images too in the webview it's like user can add text notes, and add images and bullets in the webview everything is working fine... the only thing i want is too check if user pressed return i have to offset the webview so as to avoid hidding text and better UI experience  !

Comment: the above code is not working for me in ios 6 too !! :( :( @dcorbatta

Comment: Maybe it's easy for front-end to do this than the native. When the cursor go into any input field, insert <br> at the end of the webpage may let the webview to scroll.

Comment: what if the user is typing and press return key in order to go to new line ?? @Sabbath

Comment: iDeveloper, sorry yesterday I lost conections. But the code of the first question works in iOS 6 and iOS 7, could you upload the HTML that you are using? Are you adding the script to detect the return key?

Comment: Thank you so much !! it does work in my demo project.. i will implement in actual code. !! and let you know if i succeed !!:) :)

Comment: You are a saviour to me.. i implemented in my original code and its working accordingly ! dcorbatta.. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: i dnt have 15 reputation in stackoverflow so i can't up vote.. but i will surely up vote it... when i have the priviledge !:D dcorbatta

Answer (score -1):

insert this code in `textView: shouldChangeTextInRange:`

```
if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: i already tried and found that its not working as the UIWebview recognize only DOM.