# How to get Done button action from keyboard of Webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a textfield inside UIWebview. When pressing done button, keyboard not hiding and continue to display over the view. I want to dismiss the keyboard whenever done button is pressed. Is there any way to get done button action in my swift code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321110/uiwebview-keyboard-return-key-pressed-ios-7

Comment: still not working

Comment: can you share screen shot which have you make textfield inside web view

Comment: text field is adding in html page

Comment: Do you own this html page? Can you modify the html code?

Answer (score 2):

by textfield inside a UIWebview , I take it as UITextField as a subview inside a UIWebview right ?
in that s the case you just need to implement the UITextFieldDelegate in your class, specifically this delegate method textFieldShouldReturn , which is called whenever the done button is tapped, so basically you ll have something like this :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       if (textField == correctTextField) {
           textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
```

obviously you will need to assign that controller as the textField delegate in the first place

but supposedly it s not a native textfield but rather a html or some kind of a part of the webcontent then what i would do , i would make it invoke a request with a special scheme, for exemple "hideKeyboard" and i would implement uiwebviewdelegate and test for that scheme to hide the keyboard whenever i encouter it, here s an exemple in obj c:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *URL = [request URL];
    NSString *scheme = [URL scheme];
    if ([scheme isEqualToString:@"hideKeyboard"]) {
      [self.view endEditing:true];
    }
}
```

Comment: textfield is not native, its created from webpage.

Comment: ok that s more precise, well in that case the question becomes what does the done button invoke in that "webpage"?

Comment: I just want to hide keyboard when hit return button, in webpage cant do anything related to that.

Comment: no i meant does it send a request or something ...? that way way you can implement the webview delegate , intercept that request and hide the keyboard then

Comment: so  for every url i have to check and hide keyboard right? Actually many more search bar are there in the webpage so it will be a difficult task

Comment: nope here s what i would do, make a special scheme and test on it, for exemple instead of http ... i ll use a custom scheme "hideKeyboard" .. and test on schemes for it in the delegate method, i ll put in exemple in my original comment