# Detect return button in UIWebview (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a UIWebView which I am creating a custom text editor, with a native keyboard.

I am trying to detect when the return button is pressed on the native keyboard.  I have attempted the code in this: [How to detect keyboard enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476127/how-to-detect-keyboard-enter-key) as well as [customize return key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970848/uiwebview-customize-return-key) but was not able to succeed.  How do I capture the return?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iOS Note Editor</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<script>
    function returnKeyPressed(event){
        if(window.event.keyCode == 13) document.location = "returnkeypressed:";
            return true;
        }
    }
</script> 

<style type="text/css">
    html, body {height: 100%;}
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quill.snow.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quill.bubble.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quill.core.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body onKeyPress="return returnKeyPressed(event)" style="padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;">
<div id="wrap">
<div id="editor-container" style="padding:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family:'GothamPro-Light';font-size: 15px;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quill.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quill.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="quill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ios_note_editor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

.m

```
//Not being called
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    NSLog(@"webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`body onKeyPress` when changed to `onKeyDown` fixes the issue.  Hours of headache over one word